# I get "cannot assign requested address" error

Tags: linux, apache, port, beanstalkd

I am trying to run beanstalkd

if i use 127.0.0.1 with port no 11300 it works or for the matter any other port

```
beanstalkd -d -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300
```

But if use external IP it doesn't work.

```
beanstalkd -d -l 107.0.1.5 -p 11300
```

**Should i enable the port or something** . If i should how does it work in the first case and not the second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address you pass to `beanstalkd` is the address that it `binds` to - if given, it will only accept connections to that address on the machine it runs on.  So the address 107.0.1.5 must be on one of the network interfaces on the machine you run it on.

If you want you can simply omit the `-l <address>` option to get `beanstalkd` to listen on all of the addresses on the host.